# Open graph : count actions by object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm new to the facebook open graph.
I would like to know how many times an action is performed over a given object.

eg :

- Bob cooks **chocolate cake**
- Sam cooks orange cake
- Peter cooks **chocolate cake**

I would to query how many people have cooked "chocolate cake" to get 2 as a result.

Thanks !

Comment: You can use Open graph insights to gather all sorts of data around your open graph app - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/insights/

Comment: Ok thanks ! But how to check how many actions were perform on ONE specific object.

Comment: In other words I'd like to get a count of the number of times a Facebook Open Graph action has been connected to an Object (not to a kind of object but to a spefic object)